# Streamreader cannot read file in server 500 error while reading large JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, file-io, streamreader

I'm trying to read a large-ish (2.3mb) json file and return it as a json on the web.

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"GeoJson/MaliCommunes.geo.json";
string json;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    json = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
JavaScriptSerializer JsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        
object data = JsonSerializer.DeserializeObject(json);

return new JsonResult()
{
    Data = data,
    ContentType = "application/json",
    ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
};
```

This works on localhost, but when I upload it to the server, I get a 500 error 'File not found' on this line `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))`

I've tried the following in web config:

1. Add maxRequestLength in the httpRuntime
2. Add maxJsonLength for jsonSerialization

My guess is that either the file is curropted (it does have french accented characters) or that the file is too big and is causing issues in the server.

Comment: Sounds like your AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory does not work as you expect on the server?

Comment: It does, it replaced that file with a smaller geojson file and it worked without any issue.

Comment: Do you have a memory limitation on the server?

Comment: So you already have json data. You're spending the effort to unpack that into an object, only to reserialize it again? Just serve the file.

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem as i would still have to read the file using some kind of reader.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the name of the big json file more carefully. it can have an extension that is invisible. Check the path by trying to open the json file manually. Just type the full path using Windows explorer.
2. Check the permissions at the security tab of the big json file, and compare them with the permissions of json file that works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the french accents and it worked